# How to add location manually in Google AdMob for Windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, admob

I'm just trying out to use the Google Admob for a WP8 Silverlight app.

How can I add a location manually to the AdRequest Class?

I tried this way but it didn't work.

```
  Geoposition geoposition = new Geoposition();
```

then

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.Location = geoposition.Coordinate;
```

I'm getting an error when creating the GeoPosition object saying `The type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geoposition' has no constructors defined`.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync
(
    maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
);
```

and then

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.Location = geoposition.Coordinate;
```

Check out the [pre-requisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for you app to be able to detect user's location before doing that.